# How do I get a datagridview to update from database on form load?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I'm fairly new to C# and coding in general. I've looked through similar questions and didn't have much luck fixing this.

I am making an app that stores Student details for attendance in tables, in a database. Currently when I run it, the details are added to the tables from textboxes. A button opens a separate form with a datagridview, but the details are not updated in this. If I rerun the application and open the second form, the datagridview has been updated. How do I get the datagridview to update based on information added to the table while the application is running?

This is the code that adds the details to the table

```
                using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    sc.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\corry\Desktop\StudentAttendanceBurton\Attendance.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
                    sc.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand com = sc.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        com.CommandText =
                          "insert into BUS102(\n" +
                          "  Name,\n" +
                          "  [Student ID],\n" +
                          "  Date)\n" +
                          "values(\n" +
                          "  @prm_Name,\n" +
                          "  @prm_Student_ID,\n" +
                          "  @prm_Date)";


                        com.Parameters.Add("@prm_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = student.Name;
                        com.Parameters.Add("@prm_Student_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = student.StudentID;
                        com.Parameters.Add("@prm_Date", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = student.Date;


                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
```

This is the code for the form that has the datagridview

```
public partial class AttendanceForm : Form

{

    public AttendanceForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bUS102BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.bUS102BindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.attendanceDataSet);

    }

    private void AttendanceForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'attendanceDataSet.BUS102' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.bUS102TableAdapter.Fill(this.attendanceDataSet.BUS102);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private DataSet m_ds = new DataSet();

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=YOURSql;Initial Catalog=YOURDB;Integrated Security=True")) {

            // set command
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM YourTable", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(m_ds);

            // bind data to dataGrid
            dataGridView1.DataSource = m_ds.Tables[0];

            // refresh Data
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            conn.Close();
        }


    }

    private void cmdChangeData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // add new row explicit 
        DataRow nr = m_ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
        nr[0] = "0000";
        nr[1] = "xxxx";

        // add new row to DataSet (just in memory, NOT TO DB)
        m_ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(nr);

        // Refresh Data
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The first lot of code you posted for form load works great.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh datagridview

```
this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Comment: I tried adding this to the AttendanceForm_Load method and it doesn't work before or after the fill code. Where in the code should I be putting that?

Comment: The logic is: in Form.Load fill data, bind the data adapter to DataGridView and refresh data